# Indexpath.row inside custom cell class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cells, indexpath

How can I figure out the indexpath.row of an active cell in a function that's inside the custom cell class?

I use this:

```
protocol ItemTableViewCellDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(text: String, cell: ItemTableViewCell)
}

class ItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var itemTitle: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var date: UILabel!

    var delegate: ItemTableViewCellDelegate?


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        itemTitle.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let text = textField.text {
            delegate?.textFieldDidEndEditing(text: text, cell: self)

        }
        //BTW: everything below this comment runs every time I want it to, so no problem about that
        items.insert(itemTitle.text!, at: //(Here I want the indexpath))
    }


}
```

So, I want to update my array as the textfield's change. In order to do that, I need to figure out the index path.row. I tried putting it in as so:
    `items.insert(itemTitle.text!, at: indexPath.row)`

But it doesn't let me do that.

If this isn't possible to do in the cell class, I'm open to ideas how it could be done inside the main class, too.

a screenshot of my view:

[image]

Comment: Where is the `items` array defined?

Comment: The cell should have a delegate that it can inform that its text changed which will update the data model.

Comment: Instead of a delegate you could also use closures.

Comment: The array is global.(I know, it's a bad habit) I defined it before the main class.

Comment: @dan  how would I do this?

Comment: @vikingosegundo, meaning what?

Comment: Meaning: search for it.

Comment: I ended up using tags in textfields to solve this problem. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: as rmaddy commented before: tags are not a correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add an IndexPath variable in your ItemTableViewCell class

```
var indexPathForCell: IndexPath?
```

And in your parent view controller class cellForRowAtIndexPath:-

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! ItemTableViewCell

cell.indexPathForCell = indexPath

return cell
```

Comment: This works most of the time but sometimes it won’t set for a cell and it